# Unable to Update first_name and last_name Columns in public.profiles Table Using Supabase (React Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile, supabase, supabase-js

I'm working on a project that uses Supabase as the backend, and I've set up a public.profiles table to store user profile information. The table structure looks like this:

```
create table
  public.profiles (
    id uuid not null,
    first_name text null,
    last_name text null,
    constraint profiles_pkey primary key (id),
    constraint profiles_id_fkey foreign key (id) references auth.users (id) on delete cascade
  ) tablespace pg_default;
```

I want to be able to update the `first_name` and `last_name` columns in this table when a user updates their profile information. To do this, I've created the following functions in my application using Supabase:

```
// Function to update profile information
export async function addData(firstName, lastName) {
  try {
    const { data, error } = await supabase
      .from('profiles')
      .update({ first_name: firstName, last_name: lastName })  // Problematic line
      .eq('id', userID);

    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }

    // Return some success data if needed
    return { success: true };
  } catch (error) {
    return { error: error.message };
  }
}
```

However, when I call this function to update the first_name and last_name columns, it doesn't seem to work as expected. The data doesn't get updated, and I'm not sure why.

- I've checked the Supabase table structure, and both `first_name` and `last_name` columns are defined as null, so they should allow updates.
- I've ensured that I'm passing the correct userID to the eq condition when updating the record.
- I've checked that firstName and lastName are not null being passed into addData().
- I've checked that users can view, add, and update their own profile. (I can sucessfully view my profile, so I once again am sure that I have a session, and can view my profiles row, which is the same rule for updating)

Comment: If the data isn't being updated, you should see an error. What error do you see?